# Solidity inserting array as map value after _setTokenURI on ERC721

Tags: arrays, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I want to assign an array as a value type of a map named dictBasic after function **_mint** and **_setTokenURI** from erc721. something like this:

```
contract Implement721 is ERC721URIStorage{
uint256 public tokenCounter;
mapping(address => uint[]) public dictBasic;


constructor() ERC721("alvinChris", "ACH")  {
    tokenCounter = 100;
}

function saveData(address _address_sender, string memory _tokenURI)
public returns(address, uint256){
    uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
    _mint(_address_sender, newItemId); //mint function
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, _tokenURI); //setTokenURI
    
    //inserting to map
    dictBasic[_address_sender].push(tokenCounter);
    
    tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
    
    return (_address_sender, newItemId);
}
```

I can assign successfully, but **the question is can I make sure that the _mint and _setTokenURI is done before inserting array to Map.** can someone give me the example on handling this case.

The idea that come in my mind is like **IF** logic, when **_mint** and **_setTokenURI** is not done, then pending assigning value to Map until its done.

Thankyou for the help